# Get most popular domains from log

Tags: shell, grep

I am trying to get most popular domain from a log file

The log format is like this

```
197.123.43.59,   27/May/2015:01:00:11 -0600, https://m.facebook.com/
```

I am interested only with the domain and i want an output as follows

```
XXXX facebook.com
```

where XXXX is the number of similar entries in logs

A one liner unix command anyone

Edit

I tried the following

`grep -i * sites.log  | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head  -10   &> popular.log`

but popular.log is empty , implying that command is wrong

Comment: this is quite broad. Post more representative data together with desired output for that part. Also, what did you try_

Comment: @fedorqui  i added my try .

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose of `grep -i * sites.log`. Also, your input says `https://m.facebook.com` and your output `facebook.com`. Does this mean that you want the https part to be removed and just keep the domain? Try to improve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -nle '$d{$1}++ if m!//([^/]+)!; END {foreach(sort {$d{$a} <= $d{$b}} keys(%d)) {print "$d{$_}\t$_"};}' your.log
```

if you don't mind perl

Comment: Hmm... I believe it should be in the descending order. Anyway, you can play with `$d{a} <= $d{$b}` in the `sort`, for instance, change it to `$d{a} >= $d{$b}`

Comment: Oh! Just noticed a typo. Missed a dollar sign... Updating the answer

Comment: Your answer does not describe so much what it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

uniq -c counts unique occurences, but requires sorted input.
sort sorts a stream of data
grep has a flag -o which returns only the output that matched the regex

These three parts put together is what you need to perform map/reduce on this and get the data you want.

```
grep -o '[^.]*\.[^.]*$' logfile | sort | uniq -c
```

The grep gets only the single topdomains and the domain name, all the entries are sored by the sort and the uniq counts the occurences.

Adding a sort -n at the end will give you a list where the top most entries are the highest

```
grep -o '[^.]*\.[^.]*$' logfile | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```